# Postgres - BDR replication - problem with auto_increment primary key

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, database-sequence, postgres-bdr

I have a cluster of Postgres BDR that has 2 nodes (multi master replication).
I've created a table with auto increment primary key as follow:

```
create table t1 (id serial primary key, name text);
```

I've added some values on that table from node1:

```
insert into t1(name) values('foo');
```

and now when I try to add another value into this table from node2, I receive that error:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "t1_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.
```

Comment: Please provide the insert query that you try

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that both databases have their own sequences, which are local to the database and not replicated. That causes the replication conflicts.

You can do the following:

- Use a BDR-proprietary *global sequence*.
- Use a sequence with `START 1 INCREMENT2` in one database and `START 2 INCREMENT 2` on the other one, so that sequence value cannot collide.
- Use UUIDs that are globally unique.

Comment: Thanks :) I will use global sequence. Is it possible to set node1 to start from 1 and node2 from 1000000 ?

Comment: I don't know much about BDR global sequences. But with normal sequences that would work fine. Better is to use even and odd numbers, though.